# ASP.Net MVC HTML Table Show name instead of ID of the record

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, html-table

I am stuck on how to achieve this.

I want to display the name of the Food and Drink items in the data table instead of showing the ID value it represents.

[Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxLK2.png)

For example, in the pic above, Food_ID "1", should be showing "Burger".

My controller index method which sets up the data and sends it to view. Please note, the data has been set up of how I will get it from a current database:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
    /*
        Data is added locally.
     */
    List<Food> FoodList = new List<Food>();
    List<Drink> DrinkList = new List<Drink>();
    List<Combination> CombinationList = new List<Combination>();

    // Add some food items
    FoodList.Add(new Food() { Food_ID = 1, Food_Name= "Burger" });
    FoodList.Add(new Food() { Food_ID = 2, Food_Name = "Chips" });

    // Add some drink items
    DrinkList.Add(new Drink() { Drink_ID = 1, Drink_Name = "Coke" });
    DrinkList.Add(new Drink() { Drink_ID = 1, Drink_Name = "Pepsi" });

    // Create 2 combinations.
    CombinationList.Add(new Combination { Combination_ID = 1, Food_ID = 1, Drink_ID = 1 });
    CombinationList.Add(new Combination { Combination_ID = 2, Food_ID = 1, Drink_ID = 2 });

    return View(CombinationList);
}
```

Below is a simple view which shows my list via the data table on HTML:

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication4.Models.Combination>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Combination_ID)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Food_ID)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Drink_ID)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Combination_ID)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Food_ID)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Drink_ID)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Any advice on how to achieve this?

Comment: Are you using a library? This code shouldn't be possible with HTML and JS

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention. Question updated. I am using ASP.net MVC.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to display the name of the Food and Drink items in the data
> table instead of showing the ID value it represents.

You need add name to your CombinationList. Below is a work demo, you can refer to it.

Combination:

```
 public class Combination
    {
        public int Combination_ID { get; set; }    
        public int Food_ID { get; set; }
        public int Drink_ID { get; set; }
        public string Food_Name { get; set; }
        public string Drink_Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller:

```
CombinationList.Add(new Combination { Combination_ID = 1, Food_ID = 1, Drink_ID = 1 , Food_Name = "Burger", Drink_Name = "Coke" });
CombinationList.Add(new Combination { Combination_ID = 2, Food_ID = 1, Drink_ID = 2, Food_Name = "Chips" , Drink_Name = "Pepsi" });
```

Index view:

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Combination_ID)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Food_Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Drink_Name)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Combination_ID)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Food_Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Drink_Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Hi @Maz Programmer, any update? If my answer help you resolve your issue, could you please accept as answer?
 If not, could you please follow up to let me know? 
Refer to:[How to access an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) Thanks.